# javascript: передача текста из input в ф-цию и вывод на textarea

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем есть ф-ция шифровки Цезаря

```
function caesarCipher(str, num) {
num = num % 26;
var lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
var newStr = '';
for(var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStr.length; i++){
var currentLetter = lowerCaseStr[i];
if(currentLetter === '') {
    newStr += currentLetter;
    continue;
}


var currentIndex = alphabet.indexOf(currentLetter);
var newIndex = currentIndex + num;
if(newIndex > 25) newIndex = newIndex - 26;
if(newIndex < 0) newIndex = newIndex + 26;
if(str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) {
newStr += alphabet[newIndex].toUpperCase();
}
else newStr += alphabet[newIndex];
}
return newStr;
}
```

И я хочу чтобы текстовые данные с инпута передались в ф-цию

```
<input type="text" class="input_c" placeholder="Ввведіть текст" id="usertext">
```

А когда ф-ция выполнится, то переделаные текстовые данные из переменной newStr передались в textarea

Comment: Вопрос-то в чём?)) И что такое `num` в функции?

Comment: num это сдвиг по алфавиту

Comment: А откуда он берётся?

Comment: console.log(caesarCipher('слово', num));

Comment: но `num` это ведь какое-то значение. откуда это значение должно браться? что за сдвиг по алфавиту? чей сдвиг?

Comment: я понял, допустим я создам 2 инпут для num и повторю начальный вопрос

Comment: а сдвиг по алфавиту это когда вводишь слово и пишешь какое-то значение для num, например 1 то слово abcd будет cdef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function caesarCipher(str, num) {
    num = num % 26;
    var lowerCaseStr = str.toLowerCase();
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
    var newStr = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < lowerCaseStr.length; i++) {
        var currentLetter = lowerCaseStr[i];
        if (currentLetter === '') {
            newStr += currentLetter;
            continue;
        }


        var currentIndex = alphabet.indexOf(currentLetter);
        var newIndex = currentIndex + num;
        if (newIndex > 25) newIndex = newIndex - 26;
        if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = newIndex + 26;
        if (str[i] === str[i].toUpperCase()) {
            newStr += alphabet[newIndex].toUpperCase();
        } else newStr += alphabet[newIndex];
    }

    return newStr;
}

// Установка события клика по кнопке и установка действий, которые нужно совершить при клике
document.querySelector('#get-result').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Берём значение строки с инпута
    let text = document.querySelector('#usertext').value;
    // Берём значение смещение строки с другого инпута
    let shift =  +document.querySelector('#shift').value;
    // Передаём значения в функцию и забираем результат
    let caesarCipheredStr = caesarCipher(text, shift);

    // Публикуем результат в textarea
    document.querySelector('#result').value = caesarCipheredStr;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input_c" placeholder="Ввведіть текст" id="usertext" value="abcd">
<input type="text" class="input_c" placeholder="сдвиг" id="shift" value="1">
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="get-result" value="CLICK ME">
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, все работает. P.S. я новичек в JS не ожидал такой быстрой помощи.

Comment: @denchik_old  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   ... Если ответ помог - можно ткнуть на галочку напротив ответа))